# Debugging Babelua in VS2013 error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, lua, babelua

So I downloaded VS2013 with the babelua plugin. Everything works perfect, but when debugging my code it opens the lua.exe command window and closes it immediately after executing it.

I have a test.lua file with a print("hello") statement in it. I can see the printed output for 0.5 secs and then the command window gets closed immediately.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Try `print'Hello'; io.read()`

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!